# Approval workflow with email notifications

Tags: workflow, approval-process

I am new to the Sharepoint workflow process and I am trying to do the following:

1. When the user creates a new item in a list, I'd like them to be prompted to select an approver from a company Outlook address book.
2. I'd then like the approver to receive an email that they have an item awaiting their approval then be able to approve or reject the item with comments.
3. For a rejection, I'd like the original user to be emailed of the rejection and comments.
4. For an approval, I'd like the original user to be notified of the approval and then a second notification to go to a group distribution listed on our company address book.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to create or modify a column in the list to be required. This list column can be named something like "Approver" and users that create the item list will be required to enter in this information.
2. This will be where the workflow will come in. You can create a SharePoint Designer workflow that will "Start an Approval Process" with the "Approver" as the first recipient.

3 & 4. This is handled in SharePoint Designer by the Approval Process action.

Here are a couple links to get you started with SharePoint Designer:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-workflow-HA010100591.aspx
http://svengillis.blogspot.com/2011/01/sharepoint-designer-2010-action-start.html

Comment: Thank you-I will take a look at the link. I have created a column that is labeled approver but it does not show up in the workflow when I do "Start an Approval Process" and then select the Current Item and the columns appear in the selection box. Only the basic columns such as created by, modified by, ID, etc. show up. I'll review the links you provided (thanks again) and see if I'm messing something up- which I'm certain I am.

Comment: For the Approval process, you will have an email template that you can edit. This is the Approvers task is created, and the recipient will be the Approvers column.

Comment: Your links helped greatly- thank you. My workflow is working with the slight exception of having the approval email triggered when Reject is selected. Any thoughts?

Comment: There should be a section in the SPD Workflow where you can change what Rejecting a document does. It will already have "Send an Email" to the Approvers on a stage, you can delete that action.